# Can Geth be installed with Parity?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I have installed parity and it runs for PoA. When I try to install geth it fails -

```
sudo apt-get install ethereum
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ethereum is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ethereum' has no installation candidate
```

I want to use web3 functions with parity and hence I want to use geth attach. Can geth be installed with parity?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 was the issue. I installed the unstable version of geth and the install worked.